# .htaccess rewrite rule for URL with round bracket

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The company I work for just recently sent out a mass email and got the URL for the footer wrong.  The correct URL is `/email/footer.png`, but the email has the URL `/email/footer.png)` (note the trailing bracket).

I have tried the following .htaccess RewriteRule with no luck.  RewriteEngine is on, mod_rewrite.c is loaded, and rewrites are working for a number of other RewriteRules:

```
RewriteRule ^/email/footer\.png\)$ /email/footer.png
```

Does anyone know the fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the leading slash from your uri pattern

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^email/footer\.png\)$ /email/footer.png [L,R]
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll accept this as the answer in 6 minutes when SO lets me :)